# Sql Performance issue about subquery and temp table

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, subquery

I have a very weird problem concerning a subquery in a statement.

A little background:

We have a service running for our products where I first get all products the user has access to. After that I will filter out the products the client doesn't want.

I've made this with parameterized temp table and delete queries..

As such, this is what most of our queries look like:

```
DELETE FROM @total 
WHERE Number NOT IN (SELECT Id 
                     FROM ProductTable 
                     WHERE Something = @something)
```

The one where it goes wrong is when we try to filter on a datetime

When I use the following in the stored procedure

```
DELETE FROM @total 
WHERE Number NOT IN (SELECT * 
                     FROM ProductTable 
                     WHERE DateTimeColumn > @ParameterDateTime)
```

If we use this subquery outside of the stored procedure, it works within seconds. Inside the stored procedure, it takes 81500 milliseconds

We have tried to add `with (nolock)` to the table but that didn't change anything.

Adding everything in a temp table before doing the delete and then deleting based on the temptable did work.

```
SELECT PackagedProductId 
INTO #temp2 
FROM ProductTable WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE DateTimeColumn > @ParameterDateTime

DELETE FROM @total          
WHERE Number NOT IN (SELECT * FROM #temp2)
```

My question is as followed:

- Why does it take 81500 milliseconds when I place it as a subquery in the delete statement while it works within milliseconds when I use it out side of the stored procedure?
- Why does it work properly if I use a temp table?

If you require any more information on this subject, please feel free to ask.

### Edit:

```
DECLARE @total IntListType; --IntListType = User defined table type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntListType] AS TABLE([Number] [int] NULL)
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of the @total table.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go

```
DELETE FROM @total  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ProductTable 
                  WHERE Id = @total.Number 
                  AND Something = @something)
```

or

```
DELETE FROM @total  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ProductTable 
                  WHERE Id = @total.Number 
                  AND DateTimeColumn > @ParameterDateTime)
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a different aproach.. i'm looking for the reason why it does work with a temp table and not with a subquery

Comment: In this case I would suggest you to exmaine your Execution Plan, and pay attention to each and every setp sql server is taking to execute this query and see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Why are you looking for the reason if you're not going to change anything?

Comment: We have already changed something, as you can read in my question. Now I am trying to understand why.. and the execution plan of sql server has proven a lot of times to me that it is incorrect, as such I will not rely my hopes on that

Comment: Also the amount of information you have provided in your question is just about enough to give you an alternate way to get the same results but not enough to actually diagonse the issue.